# How to get verbose output for undefined reference error using -v in clang (Android-Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, clang

Whenever you get a linker error in Android Studio it suggests you to use -v to see invocation, but where to put the -v command to get the "verbose output" ([according to llvm clang command guide](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html))?

Already tried:

```
externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -v"
            }
        }
```

which is not changing anything in the output as far as i noticed and

> --stacktrace --debug

in

```
Settings > Compiler > Command-line Options
```

Which is showing way more output but not what I am looking for!
Thank you very much for your help in advance!

**EDIT**

Since i am compiling C files i obviously had to use cFlags. Now the gradle file looks as follows (thx to @Alex Cohn):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<my_id>"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cFlags "-v"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Adding following pre-processor command in a few C-classes i did not notice they were missing it, i was able to get rid of my linker error about the missing reference:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif   

// your includes and your code here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: have you tried `cppFlags "-frtti", "-fexceptions", "-v"` ?

Comment: Just tried without any success. cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions" was autogenerated and i only added the -v there btw

Comment: It's strange; actually, for me both comma-separated list and quoted string with spaces work. You should check your `app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/android_gradle_build.json` file. But I have a hypothesis: maybe you are compiling a C file?

Comment: Oh yes, I am! How do i have to change the flag statement then? cFlags do not worked?!

Comment: for me, **cFlags** worked. But don't put `"-frtti -fexceptions"` in **cFlags**, the C compiler will complain

Comment: Yes i did. Compiler is not complaining and i am still receiving "(use -v to see invoca" but the remaining letters of the message are strangely missing now. I am using NDK 15.1.4, CMake 3.6.4 and LLDB 2.3.3. Thank you for the good hints so far

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148222/discussion-between-alex-cohn-and-int-ermedi-8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -v"` works as well as `cppFlags "-frtti", "-fexceptions",  "-v"` for **clang++** tasks, that is, to get verbose output for **.cpp** or **.cxx** files compilation.
2. `cFlags "-v"` works to produce verbose output for **.c** files compilation.
3. To produce verbose output for link step, edit your **CMakeLists.txt** file, add `-v` to the relevant **target_link_libraries** statement, e.g.

   ```
   target_link_libraries(myjnilib android log -v)
   ```
4. All above may not be enough to understand and fix *undefined reference* error.

Comment: In my case the linker error was the missing pre-processor command in just a few C-files (see Update 2 in my answer). I needed that command since i was using the default .cpp file created by Android Studio as my Java-Interface class...  Thank you ver much for your help and time @Alex Cohn

Comment: what additionally helped me out was setting "--debug" as Command-line Options in Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment (AS 3.0). Then i was able to see some of the missing linker references - consider to add this in your list